# Calculate amount of text

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
     message
------------ 
01d,2s3,1wee     (nvarchar)   
 01,32,32154,    (nvarchar)                
      df,g,d,    (nvarchar)
     dd,12,2     (nvarchar)
```

I dont know how to achieve the result below and to take account to the ',' in the end of the cell. The data in the list can be changed daily.

Requested result

```
     message  Count
------------  -----
01d,2s3,1wee      3
 01,32,32154,     3
      df,g,d,     3
      dd,12,2     3
```

// DWD

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: ',' can be at the end or NOT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @table table(message varchar(20))
insert into @table values('01d,2s3,1wee');
insert into @table values('01,32,32154,');              
insert into @table values('df,g,d,');          
insert into @table values('dd,12,2');  

SELECT message
,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(REVERSE(message),1,1) = ','  THEN 
  LEN(message) - LEN(REPLACE(message, ',', ''))   ELSE 
( LEN(message) - LEN(REPLACE(message, ',', '')) +1 )END As Count
FROM @table
```

Comment: +1 Slick... I don't know why I just didn't adjust the count if there was a trailing comma instead of going through the trouble of stripping it then counting.

Answer (score 0):

This approach checks if the final character is a `,`, and then removes it if it is...

it then compares the length of the original message to the length of the message with all `,` removed to determine how many `,` existed originally.

```
select
    len(message) - len(replace(message, ',', '')) as wordCount
from
(
    select 
        case
            when right(rtrim(message),1) = ',' 
            then substring(rtrim(message),1,len(rtrim(message))-1)
            else message 
        end as message
) trimmed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT message
  ,[Count] = LEN(CASE WHEN RIGHT(message, 1) = ',' THEN message ELSE message + ',' END) - LEN(REPLACE(CASE WHEN RIGHT(message, 1) = ',' THEN message ELSE message + ',' END, ',' ,''))
  FROM yourtablename
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to get rid of the trail ",", and then count the length of the original string and substract the length of the string replacing "," with nothing. Something like this:

```
SELECT message, LEN(Newmessage) - LEN(REPLACE(Newmessage,',','')) + 1 [Count]
FROM (SELECT message, CASE WHEN RIGHT(message,1) = ',' THEN LEFT(message,LEN('01,32,32154,')-1)  ELSE 
        message END AS Newmessage
       FROM YourTable) A
```

This assumes that there is no trailing spaces on your columns, otherwise you should use `RTRIM`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT message
, 1 + LEN(message) - REPLACE ( message , ',' , '' ) AS count
FROM my_table
```

The tick consists in counting the number of comas (",") in the column.
For this, it calculates the difference between the string and the same string without the coma.